# C++ User defined function to populate an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, user-defined

I'm just using `cout` to check if the function worked correctly. The `cout` that's in the function works and the output is 17 which is the first number in the text file. However, the `cout` in the `main()` function outputs 0. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double arrayPop();

int main()
{
    double X[10];
    double Y[10];

    arrayPop();

    cout<<Y[0];

    return 0;
}

double arrayPop()
{
    string horAxis, vertAxis;

    ifstream input;
    input.open("lin_reg-2.txt");

    input>>horAxis;
    double X[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        input>>X[i];
    }

    input>>vertAxis;
    double Y[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        input>>Y[i];
    }

    cout<<Y[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Because in the main() function you declared some vectors with no initialization. There is no relation between the X and Y arrays in main() and arrayPop(). You should pass them by parameters with the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your array as a **parameter** to the method `arrayPop()`.

Then you would have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void arrayPop(double X[], double Y[], const int size);

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    double X[size];
    double Y[size];

    arrayPop(X, Y, size);

    cout<<Y[0];

    return 0;
}

void arrayPop(double X[], double Y[], const int size)
{
    string horAxis, vertAxis;

    ifstream input;
    input.open("lin_reg-2.txt");

    input >> horAxis;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        input >> X[i];
    }

    input >> vertAxis;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        input >> Y[i];
    }

    cout<<Y[0]<<endl;
}
```

PS: I suggest you read about [Variable Scope in C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm).

Comment: This made so much sense and helped a lot. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Hi keyrimee, if you think this answers your question, then you may consider to mark it as the accepted answer